# Scala: class constructor args not visible outside

Tags: scala

Here is my class -

```
class Component(name: String, kind: String,
                 signature: ComponentSignature) {
  val steps = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[StreamAssignment]

  def addStep(assignment: StreamAssignment) = {
    steps += assignment
  }
}
```

I have the following usage somewhere else -

```
def addSource(src: Component) = {
  sources += (src.name, src)
}
```

I am getting an error that Component does not have a field "name".

My understanding is, a constructor arg, as far as visibility is concerned, is like a val declared inside the class. What am I missing?

Comment: I thought you had to specify an access modifier for it to implicitly create a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to be visible in outside of class constructor parameter, you should use `val` with construct parameter, like:

```
class Component(val name: String, val kind: String,
                 val signature: ComponentSignature) {
```

Comment: Thanks. Totally missed that. My bad.

Comment: Or use `case class`, that automatically makes the whole first parameter list `val`s.